# Tasker : create a bubbled floating windows?

Tags: android, tasker

What i wanted to do, and didn't find any suitable solution, is :

- create a scene in tasker (no problem on doing it :) )
- display this scene on overlayed mode on other app (ex: waze,). Overlay is mandatory (as i know but i am maybe wrong) to let's the underlayed application work and refresh screen normally
- allow interaction with button on the scene, just like we can do it if i choose the dialog mode for my scene. The problem with dialog mode is that the underlayed apps screen does not refresh.

In fact what i wanted to to is to display some button when i am running waze, to allow me to sens ETA Sms to my wife, or skip to the next track on my musics apps, or close waze quickly.....

**As a resume** i want to do what is

- create floating windows like offered by apps like [Overlays](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.applay.overlay)
- but only using tasker

Best regards
Best

Answer (score 0):

Please share some images of your requirements so that we can help you better but anyways I found a solution maybe it'll help you with some little customization. 
According to my understanding, you need something like this:

[image]

You can download the whole project and customize it according to your requirements from  [Here](https://github.com/rahulrj/Apple-Music-Animation?utm_source=android-arsenal.com&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=5545)

Comment: really ty for providing me an answer. But i did realise that my english is really bad, and i didn't choose the right words. I have to rewrite the question. TY